# Passing ClientId of a textbox to use it in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

this is my control:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_rol" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"  runat="server" BorderColor="#E0E0E0" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </strong>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnGuardar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/boton.guardar.jpg"  OnClientClick="ValidaCajadeTextoVacia(document.getElementById('<%=txt_rol.ClientId%>'));MensajeCargandoJQUERY();"/>
```

---

The problem is, that i can't get the Id of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, right off the bat I can tell you that there's a syntax issue in the code. It should be:

```
'<%= txt_rol.ClientID %>'
```

There may be other obstacles you need to overcome here too. For example, if these controls are nested in a `GridView` you won't be able to reference the control that way.

Comment: I'm not using a gridview, i just use a masterpage, and inside marterpage is the form where im trying to get the clientId, the thing is that when i try to use '<% %>', i don't even get the autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```
function masterClick(clicked, controlID) {
    var dynCtrl = clicked.id.substring(0, clicked.id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
    var tBox = document.getElementById(dynCtrl + controlID);
    tBox.value = "";
    tBox.focus();
}
```

Then call from your image button like...

```
masterClick(this,'txt_rol');
```

change tBox.value and focus to whatever action you like, but should have access to the control in JavaScript now. You can add in a check like " if (tBox) " to ensure you have an object. The downside is the static reference to the control within the inline javascript, and you have to adjust when the calling control is in a different container, grid, panel, etc.

Comment: this isn't exactly what i was looking for, but it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output with View Source and you will understand what is happening. You'll have to set the `OnClientClick` property server-side (`onload`). Or find a way to bind it `OnClientClick='<%#SomeProperty%>'`.

Another option could be to use jQuery to find your control:

```
$("input:text[id*=txt_rol]")
```

By the way: your JavaScript won't work if someone pastes in the textbox using the mouse (right-click/paste).